# how do I resize an entry using gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtkmm

How would I set a specific size for an entry in gtkmm and c++, as the set_default_size method allows to make the entry bigger if you need but I need to make the entry smaller and stop the length from scaling if the window is stretched

```
nameEntry.set_size(10, 10);
dobEntry.set_size(10, 10);
```

with this I get:

```
error: ‘class Gtk::Entry’ has no member named ‘set_size’;
```

Comment: what is the real type of the element you want to resize ? *Gtk::Entry* or a sub class ?

Comment: The real type is the Gtk::Entry